# When to use Modernizr from /bin vs src/modernizer.js

Tags: javascript, windows-10, modernizr

I'm going through this great [MEAN tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/making-mean-apps-with-google-maps-part-i#setup-the-routes-+-server-+-testing-the-api), and the instructions have the user downloading Modernizr from Bower. The issue that I, and others, have run into is that we receive this error in the developer console when running the web app:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

and it specifically points to this line in *../bower_components/modernizr/bin/modernizr"*

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

I'm on Windows 10, and I understand that Windows does not understand the *shebang* (*#!*) as that is a Unix thing, as far as I know.

**QUESTION:**

If I download my own build of Modernizr, or simply refer to the version of it found at *src/modernizer.js*, will this behave any differently than the version in the bin folder?

Also, if I were to stick with the version found in */bin*, how would I get it to work on Windows?

Comment: Windows does not understand nothing in this line `#!/usr/bin/env node`. The path is a UNIX path too. Yo must to convert in a `.bat` file and execute it as in windows with the correct path (`c:\Some weird windows folder\your correct path`)

Comment: How do you convert that file? Just change the extension?

Comment: Not exactly, Windows commands are different from Unix commands